# How to completely remove a library?

Tags: uninstall

I want to completely remove `libfreenect` from my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop. Right now, when I run `locate libfreenect` I get this:

```
~$ locate libfreenect
/home/elgarbe/git/libfreenect2
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libfreenect0.5.rules
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/libfreenect
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect.a
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect.so
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect.so.0.5
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect.so.0.5.1
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect_nodelet.so
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect_sync.a
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect_sync.so
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect_sync.so.0.5
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libfreenect_sync.so.0.5.1
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig/libfreenect.pc
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/libfreenect
/usr/include/libfreenect.h
/usr/include/libfreenect.hpp
/usr/include/libfreenect_audio.h
/usr/include/libfreenect_registration.h
/usr/include/libfreenect_sync.h
/usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers/libfreenect2-openni2.so
/usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers/libfreenect2-openni2.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect.so.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect.so.0.5.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect_sync.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect_sync.so.0.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreenect_sync.so.0.5.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libfreenect.pc
/usr/share/doc/libfreenect-dev
/usr/share/doc/libfreenect0.5
/usr/share/doc/ros-kinetic-libfreenect
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect0.5:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect0.5:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect0.5:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect0.5:amd64.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect0.5:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect0.5:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfreenect0.5:amd64.triggers
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ros-kinetic-libfreenect.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ros-kinetic-libfreenect.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ros-kinetic-libfreenect.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/ros-kinetic-libfreenect.triggers
```

**EDIT 1**

Trying to uninstall the package `libfreenect-dev`:

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove libfreenect-dev
[sudo] password for elgarbe: 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete «libfreenect-dev» no está instalado, no se eliminará
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 16 no actualizados.
~$ libfreenect0.5
libfreenect0.5: no se encontró la orden
~$ sudo apt-get remove libfreenect0.5
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete «libfreenect0.5» no está instalado, no se eliminará
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 16 no actualizados.
~$ sudo apt-get remove ros-kinetic-libfreenect
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete «ros-kinetic-libfreenect» no está instalado, no se eliminará
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 16 no actualizados.
~$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove libfreenect-dev
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete «libfreenect-dev» no está instalado, no se eliminará
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 16 no actualizados.
~$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libfreenect-dev
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete «libfreenect-dev» no está instalado, no se eliminará
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 16 no actualizados.
~$
```

It's in spanish and it says that there is no package with this name installed.

**EDIT 2**

After running `updatedb` I get:

```
~$ locate libfreenect
/usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers/libfreenect2-openni2.so
/usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers/libfreenect2-openni2.so.0
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreenect-bin_1%3a0.5.3-1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreenect-dev_1%3a0.5.3-1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreenect-doc_1%3a0.5.3-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreenect0.5_1%3a0.5.3-1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/ros-kinetic-libfreenect_0.5.1-0xenial-20190607-170601-0800_amd64.deb
```

**EDIT 3**

After running `apt-get clean` and `sudo updatedb` again, I just get:

```
~$ locate libfreenect
/usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers/libfreenect2-openni2.so
/usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers/libfreenect2-openni2.so.0
```

I think that I've installed it by source, but I have removed the source file. How can I uninstall them?

Comment: The final 13 lines of your output seems to show three relevant packages: `libfreenect-dev`, `libfreenect0.5`, and `ros-kinetic-libfreenect`. When you try to remove those, read the apt output carefully to ensure that you are only removing what you want to remove.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove libfreenect-dev, libfreenect0.5, ros-kinetic-libfreenect tells me that there are no packages installed with those names.

Comment: Edit your question to show the actual command input and and the complete output. Hint: Don't put commas in the command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
sudo updatedb
```

to update changes to the filesystem. After that removed items will disappear from the results shown.

---

edit:

These 4 are the installer files Ubuntu keeps on your system and you can remove these with the `rm` command.

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreenect-bin_1%3a0.5.3-1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreenect-dev_1%3a0.5.3-1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreenect-doc_1%3a0.5.3-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfreenect0.5_1%3a0.5.3-1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/ros-kinetic-libfreenect_0.5.1-0xenial-20190607-170601-0800_amd64.deb
```

So

```
rm  /var/cache/apt/archives/*libfreenect*amd64.deb
```

Do a `sudo updatebd` after removing to remove them from the results.

---

There are part of OpenNI2. Do you still have that installed?

```
/usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers/libfreenect2-openni2.so
/usr/lib/OpenNI2/Drivers/libfreenect2-openni2.so.0
```

If you do: uninstall that with the method corresponding to what you installed it with (apt -> apt remove, from source there might be an uninstaller).

Comment: No need to manually remove these files. You can run `sudo apt clean`.

Comment: That would remove every deb in there. The question was specific about these files ;)